# 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.sun:tools:jar must specify an absolute

Tags: gradle

Processing of C:\Users\asker.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.crashub\crash.shell\1.3.2\887bc9980d3f6a39f0adc79caf5b655e3761d1a\crash.shell-1.3.2.pom failed:
    'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.sun:tools:jar must specify an absolute path but is /home/tclement/plf-release-tools/tools/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/../lib/tools.jar in org.crashub:crash.shell:1.3.2

Answer (score 2):

It was found that in the pom file `.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.crashub\crash.shell\1.3.2\887bc9980d3f6a39f0adc79caf5b655e3761d1a\crash.shell-1.3.2.pom` the system path was hardcoded.

Update the path as follows:
`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
    <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${java.home}/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

`